# Euclid's algorithm for distance in 2D array

Tags: java

I want to calculate the distance between two nodes in a 2D environment. For example, I am at (13,26), and the target is at (54,38). I want to find the distance between them using Euclid's algorithm using Java.

Comment: This is trivial. Start by writing some code, try running it, then post back specific problems you encounter.

Comment: Use `Math.sqrt` to calculate the square root; everything else should indeed be trivial. What are you struggling with?

Comment: "Euclid's algorithm" calculates the GCD of two numbers, not the distance of two points. You probably meant to say "... find the Euclidean distance between them using the Pythagorean formula ...".

Answer (score 1):

If it's so trivial (Re: comments), let's just do it: :)

```
public double distance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    return Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
}
```